# nginx url pattern to memcached

Tags: url, nginx, memcached

I want to cache response for 10 minutes just in special pattern using nginx memcached module.
This is a documantation of nginx memcached module.
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMemcachedModule

```
  location / {
    set $memcached_key $uri;
    memcached_pass     name:11211;
    default_type       text/html;
    error_page         404 @fallback;
  }
```

How can i just some pattern like  to cache url contain `[0-9]{6,7}` just cache via nginx memcached modules?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean, but if I understand correctly, you should change the location block from `/` to the location that matches the URLs that you want.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady so give me the correct path for location.

Comment: what's the URL going to be like, something like `example.com/text1234567` ? or just `example.com/1234567`, or is it mixed like `example.com/text/1234567/text`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady `example.com/text/1234567/text`

Comment: are both text words always different? give me an example URL

Comment: example /blah-blah/934552/blahbla-%3f/ or /23415